# How To Bind Node-js DB Query to Web Form

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using node and postgres, I'm new to writing async function, what I'm trying to do is a very simple query that will do a total count of records in the database, add one to it and return the result. The result will be visible before the DOM is generated. I don't know how to do this, since async function doesn't return value to callers (also probably I still have the synchronous mindset). Here's the function:

```
function generateRTA(callback){
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
const qry = `SELECT COUNT(date_part('year', updated_on)) 
              FROM recruitment_process
              WHERE date_part('year', updated_on) = $1;` 
const value = [current_year]

pool.query(qry, value, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack)
    } else {
        var count = parseInt(res.rows[0].count) + 1
        var rta_no = String(current_year) + '-' + count
        callback(null, rta_no)        
    }
  })
}
```

For the front-end I'm using pug with simple HTML form.

```
const rta_no = generateRTA(function (err, res){
if(err){
    console.log(err)
}
else{
    console.log(res)
}
})


app.get('/new_application', function(req, res){
res.render('new_application', {rta_number: rta_no})
});
```

I can see the rta_no in console.log but how do I pass it back to the DOM when the value is ready?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question doesn't meet the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) criteria as you haven't included the front-end code that would let us see what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the ajax call async response, it will update the div id "div1" when it gets the response from the Node js .

app.js

```
app.get("/webform", (req, res) => {
    res.render("webform", {
        title: "Render Web Form"
    });
});


app.get("/new_application", (req, res) => {
    // Connect to database.
    var connection = getMySQLConnection();
    connection.connect();
    // Do the query to get data.
    connection.query('SELECT count(1) as cnt FROM test ', function(err, rows, fields) {
    var person;
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).json({"status_code": 500,"status_message": "internal server error"});
    } else {
        // Check if the result is found or not
        if(rows.length==1) {
            res.status(200).json({"count": rows[0].cnt});
        } else {
            // render not found page
            res.status(404).json({"status_code":404, "status_message": "Not found"});
        }
    }
});
// Close connection
connection.end();
});
```

webform.pug - Via asynchronous call

```
html
  head
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "/new_application", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result.count);
        }});
        });
  body
    div
       Total count goes here  : 
    #div1
       value loading ...
```

Comment: Awesome! that answers the questions. I modified your code a little bit and it worked! Thanks Senthil.

Answer (score 0):

That seems okay, I'm just not sure of this:

> The result will be visible before the DOM is generated

This constraint defeats the purpose of async, as your DOM should wait for the returned value to be there. Instead of waiting for it you could just render the page and once the function returns and runs your callback update the value.

Also, perhaps it's worth having a look into [promises](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. Can you give an example how to resolve the promise and append it to the dom?

Comment: This is better suited as a comment instead of an answer as it doesn't provide a concrete solution to the question.